# No java command with OpenJDK installation

Tags: java

I apologize for the novice question but I'm trying to get oriented with OpenJDK. I just installed OpenJDK but there doesn't seem to be a java command (I see javac, javah, and javap though). I'm trying to run `ant` but it isn't able to run without the java command. What am I missing?

Comment: There is something wrong with your configuration. It should be included in the package. Check if you actually have the file named `java` and if you do - check the env path.

Comment: That's a first.  Usually, it's someone who installed a JRE asking where javac is.  LOL.

Comment: Yeah it's weird - I'm thinking there's something wrong with the repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the bin directory in your OpenJDK installation and see if it has the java binary there.

If it is, depending on your OS, just add that directory to your system PATH variable.

Comment: That's the thing - it isn't there. I'm using the command apt-get install openjdk-6-jdk in Ubuntu

Comment: Check in /usr/lib/jvm and see if it has been installed there.

Comment: Have you tried locate? If you haven't got it installed, get it then index your drive. Then you can do locate java and if it's on your system, it should come up with the path. If it's not there, maybe try downloading it manually and setting it up rather than using sudo-apt?

Answer (score 1):

Also, check the `jre/bin` subdirectory if such a thing exists.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to add the jdk to your system path:

On windows, right clicking on computer (my computer) and go to properties, select advanced and click Environment Variables button.

On unix this can be done by:

```
export PATH=$PATH:{path to your jdk}
```

Comment: Yeah I can add the path just fine - problem is there's no java binary.

Comment: There probably is a binary, but it probably hasn't been placed in /usr/bin or anywhere currently in a PATH. You need to find where it has been installed to and add that to the PATH, try /usr/lib/jvm